# How to connect two draggable views in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a game kind of like a puzzle game. There are several draggable objects on the screen and users are able to connect them together. What method can I use when the user drag two objects near each other and as the user releases their finger, the two objects will be connected to together. Below is the code that I used to make two labels and make them draggable (I know its very dumb to make a function for each one but right now I just want to know how the combine of the two objects works)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 2 - 100, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height / 2 - 100, 100, 50))
    let label2 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 2 - 100, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height / 2 - 200, 100, 50))

    label.text = "Str"
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    self.view.addSubview(label)

    label2.text = "ing"
    label2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label2.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    self.view.addSubview(label2)



     let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("wasDragged:"))
    label.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    label.userInteractionEnabled = true

    let gesture2 = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("wasDragged1:"))
    label2.addGestureRecognizer(gesture2)
    label2.userInteractionEnabled = true



}

func wasDragged(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
     let translation = gesture.translationInView(self.view)
    if let label = gesture.view {

    label.center = CGPoint(x: label.center.x + translation.x, y: label.center.y + translation.y)

    }
    gesture.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)


}

func wasDragged1(gesture:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let translation = gesture.translationInView(self.view)
    if let label = gesture.view {

        label.center = CGPoint(x: label.center.x + translation.x, y: label.center.y + translation.y)

    }
    gesture.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)



}
```

Thanks for anyone who helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "connect" two views - it ignores how views and view hierarchy work.

- But you can make it "appear to connect". It'll get quickly complicated though. In your simple example one way is to have three subviews to the puzzle board: two visible ("str" and "ing"), and one invisible ("string"). Once connected, hide the "str" and "ing" and show the "string" subview. Maybe show a bit of splashy animation to really look like it's connecting.
- Another idea (depending on the type of puzzle) is to have it be a variant of the old "Concentration" game. There, the final puzzle board was hidden behind various numbered squares. In your game you might have the "pieces" have a specific position they need to be moved to (in pairs?), and when the user does it you - again - make it appear to connect, maybe with a bit of animation.

If I'm off base here - and someone truly has a way to "connect' two UIViews into one - I'll gladly remove my answer (and up vote that answer).